# Grunt and relative URL (Yeoman scaffolded with JekyllRB Generator)

Tags: gruntjs, jekyll, yeoman

I have scaffolded a Yeoman project with JekyllRB Generator[1]. Everything works great if I continue to use root relative URLs for the styles, javascript.

```
<!-- build:css({app,.tmp}) /styles/style.css -->
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

If I want to use Jekyll's baseurl, the idea is that I can re-write the above code with

```
<!-- build:css({app,.tmp}) {{ site.baseurl }}/styles/style.css -->
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/styles/style.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

where the baseurl is picked up from the Jekyll's config.yml (one for dev and an additional for production). Unfortunately, the grunt re-written files do not work, it starts writing the whole URL as folders - "somedomain.com/thefolder-from-config/style/styles.css".

Is there a way to do the normal stuff but re-write that URL reference to the domain and location that I choose in the config.yml?

Update: I'm resorting to the HTML tag BASE[2] for now. However, I'd still love to get a solution.

1. https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Answer (score 0):

The build blocks are part of the grunt usemin project, and need a local output file to write to. Check the [usemin docs](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#blocks) for more info.

I've never heard of the base element. Thanks for that.